# Barcode scanner reading only first digit

Tags: barcode-scanner, barcode

I have a question that is more technical rather than programming:

I have a machine commanded by Siemens SIMATIC S7-1200, and it has USB port where I can plug a barcode scanner.

I have 2 scanners from 2 different brands. The first one works just fine. The issue with the second one is that, when scanning 10-character barcodes it shows only the first character. If you scan something with less characters it works just fine, but when you scan 10 characters it shows only the first.

When I try them on PC in text document the both work fine.

The barcodes are CODE 128. The problematic scanner is DATALOGIC GRYPHON GM-4100. I am trying to program the barcode scanner in various ways using this manual (https://images10.newegg.com/User-Manual/User_Manual_38-129-082.pdf) but no effect.

I don't think that the issue is in the type of communication (RS232, USB) because for smaller barcodes it works. The issue should be in the symbologies options, probably in Code128 settings, but I cannot wrap my head where.

I do not have access to the PLC code.

Do you have any experience in this field? I would be extra extra extra grateful

Have a great day!

Comment: I can imagine that the amount of data "overfills" a hardware input buffer - check whether there is a barcode option for e.g. "intercharacter delay" and set that at a fairly high value to see if that works. **If it does**, set it downward "halfways" and check again, repeat until it stops working, at that point restore to a value halfway between working and nonworking values, repeat to close in on the point of breakage - by that telling where to leave it to have it functional.

Comment: This ^- as PLC:s aren't the most speedy devices...

Comment: Thank you very much, the default setting is on "No Delay". I will most definetly try this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: UPDATE: I tried with highest intercharacter delay, and all different settings for CODE 128, nothing changes.
I opened barcode generator, tuned in to CODE 128, and this is the result:
8 numbers + 1 letter = OK ...
9 numbers + 1 letter = FAIL ...
5 letter = OK ...
6 letter = FAIL ... My guess is that the barcode scanner somehow converts the letters in larger strings than the numbers and some buffer is overfilled. Just a reminder, with another scanner all the combinations above work FINE.